# How to fix fastlane Build error with gym getting error 65

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

My target have watchOS,

Here is my gym script

```
gym(
    use_legacy_build_api: true,
    workspace: "iservice.xcworkspace",
    scheme: "beta",
    configuration:"Release",
    silent: true,
    clean: true,
    output_directory:"./build",
    output_name:"service.ipa"
    )
```

Error logs.

> === BUILD TARGET WatchKit Extension OF PROJECT iservice WITH CONFIGURATION Release === target specifies product type
>   'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such
>   product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

Comment: When you execute manually the Archive works fine? seems there is some problem with the config of watchextension in the project